# Date difference between similar records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and need to get the difference between two dates for a very similar set of records. I've tried a few methods today but cannot seem to get this one to work.

**Example Table:**

```
  Payment_ID | Created_Date | Version_ID |      Status
 ----------------------------------------------------------
     1526    | 20/10/2015   |      1     | Opened
     1526    | 20/10/2015   |      2     | Verified Open
     1526    | 22/10/2015   |      3     | Assigned
     1526    | 23/10/2015   |      4     | Contact Made
     1859    | 20/10/2015   |      1     | Opened
     1859    | 20/10/2015   |      2     | Verified Open
     1859    | 22/10/2015   |      3     | Assigned
     1859    | 22/10/2015   |      3.5   | Re-Assigned
     1859    | 22/10/2015   |      4.5   | Contact Failed
     1859    | 23/10/2015   |      4     | Contact Made
     1859    | 24/10/2015   |      5     | Assigned Updated
     1859    | 25/10/2015   |      6     | Contact Made
     1859    | 26/10/2015   |      7     | Resolved
     1859    | 21/10/2015   |      8     | Closed
     1852    | 26/10/2015   |      1     | Opened
     1778    | 21/09/2015   |      1     | Opened
     1778    | 22/09/2015   |      2     | Verified Open
     1778    | 23/09/2015   |      3     | Assigned
     1778    | 24/09/2015   |      4     | Contact Made
     1778    | 25/09/2015   |      5     | Assigned Updated
```

The requirement is to return the `Payment_ID` and `StatusDateDiff` for a given `Status`, in this case the `Contact_Made` one and only the first one if a `Payment_ID` has more than one, then take the difference between that date and the previous status date for any of them.

So taking 1526 "Contact_Made" was on the `24/10/2015` and the previous status, regardless of what that was, is `23/10/2015` so the difference is `1`.

For the above it would look like this:

```
  Payment_ID | StatusDateDiff
 -----------------------------
    1526     |       1
    1859     |       1
    1852     |       0
    1778     |       1
```

I tried a few sub queries to get the `distinct Payment_ID` and `Min(Created_Date)`, but that resulted in duplicates once put together.

Also tried a Common Table Expression but that lead to the same - though I'm not too familiar with them.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What part of this is using SQL-Server, and what part is using Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAG()` (available in SQL Server 2012+):

```
select payment_id, datediff(day, prev_created_date, created_date)
from (select t.*,
             lag(created_date) over (partition by payment_id order by created_date) as prev_created_date,
             row_number() over (partition by payment_id, status order by created_date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'Contact Made' and seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but this should point you in the right direction.  You can use a windowed `ROW_NUMBER()` function to determine which values are the latest, and do a `DATEDIFF()` to find the number of days they are different.

*Edit:  I just noticed you have a SQL Server tag and an Oracle tag - this answer is for SQL Server*

```
;With Ver As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Payment_Id Order By Version Desc) Row_Number
    From    Table
)
Select      Latest.Payment_Id,
            DateDiff(Day, Coalesce(Previous.Created_Date, Latest.CreatedDate), Latest.CreatedDate) As StatusDateDiff
From        Ver     As  Latest
Left Join   Ver     As  Previous    On  Latest.Payment_Id = Previous.Payment_Id
                                    And Previous.Row_Number = 2
Where       Latest.Row_Number = 1
```